# Using of trailing slash in void element

Tags: html, trailing-slash

Since I use prettier extension to write HTML in VS code it adds trailing slashes in void elements when I format it. Then I put it into html validator to check for errors and it stated info like this "**Info: Trailing slash on void elements [has no effect](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing) and [interacts badly with unquoted attribute values](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values). I dont get it. What its trying to say? if its a  problem how can I get rid of this in prettier extension.

*Note: there were no error in my html code.*

I wanted the validator to state that the "coding is alright, good to go" something like that.

Comment: For HTML5 you do not need the trailing slash. For XHTML you need them. Prettier is adding them for XHTML compatibility. As a good habit you should always use single or double quotes on attributes. So a trailing slash will cause no issue. The W3C still gives a info warning but no critical warning so it can be disregarded.

Comment: To go straight to the answer: I think there's no way to filter that behaviour on Prettier [Prettier and closing slashes in HTML](https://github.com/orgs/mdn/discussions/242). Those 2 points mean: 1. using or not using the trailing slash has no special meaning because self closing tag are as such by html specification not because you add the slash or not; 2. there's an example shown in the link you shared, where if the attribute is not quoted, its value will be set with the trailing slash following even if you intended to give it another meaning

Comment: You’ve included two links in your question which answer it in great detail. I’m not sure what you expect us to add to what.

Comment: @DiegoD That's a good answer and you should post it as one. Prettier needs to get their act together.

Comment: @Rob I get your point but I'm very very cautious on posting answer on trivial questions. The question wasn't perfectly focused and was mixing shades of truth. The point is you can't configure Prettier to ignore those warnings but yet there's no value on hiding them. And yet those warnings are valid because the scope of validation is wider than HTML5 itself. So Prettier won't ever change that and I agree with that. People should stop using the trailing slash and avoid finding shortcuts to allow them. So stick with the warnings and don't color those as unnecessary hiding them under the carpet

Comment: @Rob In the end I just moved my comments to an answer... I didn't cite the xhtml part (my bad) .. and I just hope it's for the sake of the Q/A consistency not willing to look for gains with easy words.

Comment: Prettier should just not include them. Makes me want to not use prettier for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**Straight to the answer**: I think there's no way to filter that behaviour on Prettier (...and you shouldn't anyway).

Those 2 points you asked in your question, mean:

1. https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing

Using or not using the trailing slash has no special meaning because self closing tag are as such by html specification not because you add the slash or not; Here you can read a discussion about that: https://github.com/orgs/mdn/discussions/242

2. https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values

There's an example shown in the link you shared, where if the attribute is not quoted, its value will be set with the trailing slash following even if you intended to give it another meaning.

The question isn't perfectly focused and is mixing shades of truth.

The point is you can't configure Prettier to ignore those warnings but yet there's no value on hiding them.

And yet those warnings are valid because the scope of validation is wider than HTML5 itself. So Prettier won't ever change that and I agree with that.

**People should stop using the trailing slash and avoid finding shortcuts to allow them. So stick with the warnings and don't color those as unnecessary hiding them under the carpet.**